# Use Loop operators in a sequence diagram with RSA

Tags: loops, uml, rsa, sequence-diagram

RSA I installed on my machine.
I would use a sequence diagram .. after New -> Diagram -> Sequence Diagram insert the LifeLine

I would like the Loop combinated Fragment and a Fragment Alt combinated but which are not included in the Panel. How do I restore them?

Thanks to all who help me

Sebe

Comment: Did you try to create first the combined fragment then the life line. I am not sure but sometimes the order creation could be important.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to reset your perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Next to "Option Combined Fragment" you should see a little arrow. Click on it it'll drop down all the other combined fragments available.